# How to reduce height of tabs - angular material

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I have tabs in `angular material`. I want to reduce the size of Tabs. I tried few `styles`, still not getting

This is my code

```
<style>
::ng-deep .mat-tab-label{
 padding: 2px!important;
 height: 0px;
 min-height: 0px!important;
 margin: 3px!important;
}
</style>

<div>    
<mat-tab-group #tabRef>
  <mat-tab label="Angular">Angular Content</mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="React">React Content</mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="VueJs">VueJs Content</mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>    
</div>
```

Screenshot of tabs

[image]

How can I fix this

Comment: https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/overview#dynamic-height

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need empty space between `::ng-deep` and `.mat-tab-label`. Also add `!important` in `height`.

```
<style>
::ng-deep .mat-tab-label{
 padding: 2px!important;
 height: 0px!important;
 min-height: 0px!important;
 margin: 3px!important;
}
</style>
```

Comment: @MoxxiManagarm The person cannot post a comment yet. This isn't an excuse for the low quality answer, but more a flaw of SO

Comment: Try adding !important. It is working for me

See this: [link] (https://codesandbox.io/s/adoring-hamilton-u6bz1?file=/src/app/app.component.css)